# Нужна ли запятая перед «также»?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна запятая перед «также» или нет: «Но я знаю, что, несмотря на мои заскоки, они меня любят, также как и я их»?

Answer (score 3):

Да, нужна запятая перед союзом *также как и*, присоединяющем придаточное предложение к главному. А вот в предложении "... они меня любят так же, как и я их", *так же* в главном предложении является усилительной частицей и запятая ставится перед союзом *как*. Эти предложения различаются по смыслу. В первом утверждается, что "они меня любят и я их люблю", а во втором подчёркивается,  что "они меня любят так же (в той же степени, таким же образом), как и я их".

Answer (score 1):

Элен говорит всё верно. А для простоты можно запомнить, что всё, что начинается с *"как и"* выделяется запятыми. "Также" - союз, к нему нельзя задать вопрос. "Так же" - это указательное местоимение с частицой, к которым можно задать вопрос (*как?*), к тому же частицу "же" можно безболезненно опустить, смысл не поменяется.

Answer (score 1):

Элен неправа — возможно только раздельное написание. И предпочтительна тут запятая перед *"как",* так как акцент на том, что *они меня любят тАк же:*

> *Но я знаю, что, несмотря на мои заскоки, они меня любят так же, как и я их.*

Дело в том, что не существует аналогичного выражения со слитным *"также" (также как и).* Чтобы передать мысль, что автора также (в смысле *тоже,* а не в той же степени) любят, остаётся лишь выразиться по-другому, например:

> Но я знаю, что, несмотря на мои заскоки, моя любовь к ним взаимна

или с *также:*

> Но я знаю, что, несмотря на мои заскоки, не только я их люблю, но также и они меня.